# QGIS Custom function for report names

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function

When working with regular layouts the **@layout_name** is available  to use the layout name within the layout.
For reports @layout_name does not work.
Can the layout name be made available using a custom function?
Using the python console I have managed to get a list of the layouts (not by name) in the layout manager and reports do show up but I can't figure out how to get the name of the current one.